# MS Access SQL - Insert Query while adding an additional column into table

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, office365

I am using VBA to insert a queryset into an existing ms access 365 table with an SQL statement.

Code to insert query (working):

```
 CurrentDb.Execute "Insert Into Tablename Select temp.* From temp",dbFailOnError 'if table exists
 
 CurrentDb.Execute "Select temp.* Into Tablename From temp",dbFailOnError 'if table does not exist
```

But now, I am also trying to add values to a column not in the query (a log number) into the table for the inserted queryset. So lets say insert '1' into a column called Evtlog in the table for these records.

What I was hoping to do to add the log number into the column Evtlog (gives syntax error):

```
CurrentDb.Execute "Insert Into Tablename Select temp.* From temp Set Evtlog=1",dbFailOnError
```

But I get an error on this statement, is there anyway to combine "Select" with "Set"?

Preferably, I would prefer to use Select as the query columns can change, but I am open to other solutions - for example, can a column be added to the queryset?

Comment: just add the column with DDL - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/alter-table-statement-microsoft-access-sql

Comment: Thanks @user10186832, the column exists, but I am looking for a way to populate only the rows inserted by the query with the value 1 in this column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```vb
CurrentDb.Execute "Insert Into Tablename Select temp.*, 1 As EvtLog From temp",dbFailOnError 'if table exists
 
CurrentDb.Execute "Select temp.*, 1 As EvtLog Into Tablename From temp",dbFailOnError 'if table does not exist
```